# Cannot delete derived data in Xcode 4's organizer

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5, xcode-organizer

I'm trying to restore Code Sense, which has stopped working for my project, and it looks like the accepted way to do that is to delete the derived data.

The problem is that the project has to be open or it doesn't appear in the Organizer, and the delete button for the derived data is faded out and unable to be clicked.

My project is a dropbox folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clear **Derived Data** manually without using **Organizer**. Go to **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/** and delete every thing there, or at least the folders that start with the name of your project.

Comment: Hm, could there be something wrong with my install? ~/Library/DeveloperDeveloper doesn't seem to have an 'Xcode' folder. And a search of 'DerivedData' returns no results.

Comment: Not /Library/... but ~/Library/... **~** is your home folder.

Comment: Ah, great thanks. Though is there another step to force Xcode to reindex now?

Comment: I tried, though for what ever reason it won't index it (no new derived data).

Answer (score 0):

Better way to clear Derived Data is to use this plugin. - https://github.com/kattrali/deriveddata-exterminator

And a better way to install the plugin is to use Alcatraz - http://mneorr.github.io/Alcatraz/

It really is awesome. Try it.