# How can I avoid having to clean the project after replacing files?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Xcode 4.5.2, using cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1 for game development.

Recently, I have realized that every time I replace an image file with one of the same name, the project in my device will continue using the old one when I create a `CCSprite` with such file.

This can be fixed by simply cleaning the project.

However, now the project is rather large, and compiling after cleaning takes quite an annoying amount of time.

Is it possible to replace files and make Xcode use the correct files instead of having to clean the project?

Another simple fix is to give a different name to the new file and delete the old, then change the `CCSprite` to use the new file name. Of course, this is ridiculous so I'd like to avoid doing it.

I believe that it also happens even when I just delete the app from the device - it seems I do have to clean the project.

Comment: when you delete the file do you choose Move to Trash or Remove References?

Comment: It happens on occassion, but it shouldn't happen frequently. Perhaps clean your entire build folder, and reboot both device and Mac.

Comment: @bluestunt: I move to trash

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Hm, I haven't tried rebooting the device itself. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Organizer` in your `Xcode`. Goto the `Projects` tab.

[image]

you can see `Derived data` options. Click `Delete` near to that option, to clean your project

[image]

Comment: Actually, the delete button next to Derived Data is not enabled. The button next to Snapshots is enabled though. All unlike your screenshot :(

Comment: Delete it manually, by navigating to the following path `/Users/your_computer_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Find your project folder and delete it. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509004/cannot-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-4s-organizer#answer-9509049)