# XCode buggily loading images that aren't in my project folder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

For some reason, XCode is acting up really oddly. I have been testing XCode's ability to load images with the -hd suffix, and realized that Xcode will **load a file "welcomeBackground.jpg" regardless of whether it is actually in my project folder.**

See, this code below will not crash when compiled. And this is the first screen that is displayed when the app loads. I deleted the file "welcomeBackground.jpg" from my project folder, and **XCode still loads the file as if it were there.**

This is really freaking me out. Please help?

[image]
[image]

I am 200% sure I deleted the file from my **project folder even** and yet Xcode does not crash on line 35.

```
EDIT: To repeat, things I have tried/checked
- Cleaned project
- Deleted Derived Data
- Checked for hidden files in project folder
- Deleted app from iPhone and re-run from XCode
- Deleted the files from my project folder
- Loaded another image "sadhieia.png" and crashed Xcode 
  because Xcode couldn't find the file (as it does not 
  exist), and then tried "welcomeBackground.jpg" again 
  and Xcode somehow finds it.
```

And yet, the background **still loads...**

Comment: Did you clean & re-compile your App ?

Comment: When you say " I deleted the file from my project folder" Do you mean that you went to the directory in finder and deleted them there? Have you tried navigating to your project dir in Terminal and checking for hidden files?

Comment: CaptJak, thanks for the input. I checked for hidden files in Terminal and there were no hidden files with welcomeBackground.jpg name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Cocos2d`, if the specified image is not in your folder, it'll not crash. Instead, it'll return `nil` to your  `CCSPrite *background`.
I suggest you `Don't use Camelcase for images`.  Use `lowercases or underscores`.
 Try deleting `Derived Data`. See this for [how to delete derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509004/cannot-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-4s-organizer#answer-9509049).

Comment: Thanks for the input, arthan. But I deleted Derived Data already, yet it still insists on loading the welcomeBackground.jpg when it's not in my project folder, even after clean and deleting Derived Data

Comment: Oh my good sir.... I feel like a fool. That did the trick. Of everything I tried I skipped over restarting XCode...

THANK YOU so much!!! I would have pulled out my hair trying to get it to work. Wow... Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

Scroll the project navigator down to the bottom, to "Products," then click the disclosure arrow to show your application.

Right-click the application and choose "Show in Finder" from the contextual menu that appears. A Finder window is displayed containing your application.

Command-click the title of that window; another contextual menu appears. From that, choose the folder "Derived Data." The Finder then displays a window for that folder.

In this window, you'll see a folder whose name is that of your application, followed by a long string of letters. Trash it. If you see multiple folders bearing your application's name, trash them as well.

Rebuild your project. That should take care of the issue.

This might be a slash and burn approach, but it's solved a lot of quirky project-related issues I've experienced in Xcode after attempting to clean.

Comment: Thanks for the input, trudscousin. But I deleted Derived Data already, yet it still insists on loading the welcomeBackground.jpg when it's not in my project folder, even after clean and deleting Derived Data. I don't think that is the issue

Comment: @RaymondChan I read with interest that you substitute a bogus file name and had a crash. This implies that Xcode is loading the welcomeBackground.jpg file from *somewhere*. Have you seen if it's included in any of the frameworks that comprise your project?

Comment: @RaymondChan Here's another suggestion: Did you enter "welcomeBackground.jpg" in the search field at the bottom of the Project Navigator? If the file's hidden away someplace inside your project, it'll be revealed just the same.

Comment: thanks for the input! I searched in the bottom of the project navigator and it did not appear. Apparently all it took was a simple restart of Xcode. Thanks again!

Comment: @RaymondChan I thought your problem was very interesting, and now I've got something to remember the next time I encounter a weird situation such as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project; your image file is still cached in the build folder.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I've seriously cleaned this project at least 10 times to no avail. It can't be due to lack of cleaning the project. I even deleted the derivedData

Comment: At line 35,objective c should not crash if the resource is missing, it should return nil. If self.addChild: can tolerate being passed nil, you won't crash.

Comment: But it still loads the image "welcomeBackground.jpg"! :[ It's not being passed nil because otherwise it shouldn't display the background, but it does.