# Core Data issue: unrecognized selector when I update the data model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a project that manages a database with Core Data. This DB works fine, but I need to add a new field in a table. When I create a new version of the data model, add the field and back to create the `NSManagedObject` subclasses (autogenerated). the application finishes with an error about "unrecognized selector" in the new field that I added.

The new autogenerated table is the next:

**File.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Session;

@interface File : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fileType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pathFile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;     // NEW FIELD
@property (nonatomic, retain) Session *session;

@end
```

**File.m**

```
#import "File.h"
#import "Session.h"

@implementation File

@dynamic date;
@dynamic fileType;
@dynamic pathFile;
@dynamic name;      // NEW FIELD
@dynamic session;

@end
```

These are all the relationships in the database:

[image: Database]

And this is the creation of the entity in the code:

```
File *newFile = [File createEntity];
newFile.pathFile = pathFile;
newFile.fileType = @"Video";
newFile.name = @"Video 1";
newFile.date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
if ([sessionPicker selected] < sessions.count) {
     newFile.session = [sessions objectAtIndex:[sessionPicker selected]];
}

[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
```

And the error that I mentioned before is the next (only fails in the new field, if I comment the line to add the name of the file, the creation works fine):

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[File setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc667770'
```

I tried to remove the references to datamodel and added them again, but this fails too. Also, I tried to clean the project and remove the app of the simulator, but this fails too.

Any solution or suggestion, please?

***Edit:***

**NSLog output**

```
(lldb) po [[newFile entity] properties]
<__NSArrayM 0xc6f7340>(
(<NSAttributeDescription: 0xc2ac350>), name date, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity File, renamingIdentifier date, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null),
(<NSAttributeDescription: 0xc2ac3a0>), name fileType, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity File, renamingIdentifier fileType, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null),
(<NSAttributeDescription: 0xc2ac3f0>), name pathFile, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity File, renamingIdentifier pathFile, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null),
(<NSAttributeDescription: 0xc2ac440>), name syncID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity File, renamingIdentifier syncID, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null),
(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0xc2acc50>), name session, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity File, renamingIdentifier session, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, destination entity Session, inverseRelationship files, minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1
)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove .h/.m from build phases and add them again?

Comment: Did you update the 'current' model version?

Comment: Did you create a new model version? If yes, did you set the "current version" to the new model version?

Comment: He removed the app from simulator so for now migration would not be a problem, I guess.

Comment: Yes to all: I try now to remove the .h/.m from build phases and the app still failing, and the current model version is the new model version

Comment: I would try to rename that field as for example `name2` and generate `.h.m` again. Have a try and see what happens. Just for testing. In addition, you could also try to remove `.h.m` and see if duplicates are there. Maybe you did not override the previous generated classes.

Comment: Very strange. Can you show the NSLog output of `[[newFile entity] properties]` ?

Comment: Finally, do a **Clean Build Folder**. Open **Products** and press **alt**. Instead of **Clean**, **Clean Build Folder** will appear.

Comment: I added the ouput in the question Martin. Noe, I will try the solution of flexaddicted

Comment: I rename the field and generated the new files again, and after, I clean build folder. The code recognize the new field, but still fails... T.T

Comment: Try to remove derived data.

Comment: @JoséÁngelCuadradoMingo: According to the "properties" output, `File` does not have a "name" attribute. Double-check that the new attribute is added to the new/current model version (and not to the old one).

Comment: @MartinR: yes, the attribute is added, maybe something is not updated, although I changed the references many times... How can I sure that the references are fine introduced??

Comment: @flexaddicted: I don't understand your suggestion

Comment: About to remove derived data, what do you refer with derived data?

Comment: Hold the "Option" key and select Product->Clean Build Folder... from the Xcode menu.

Comment: I did too, but the bug continues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509004/cannot-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-4s-organizer. @MartinR Already suggested before. :)

Comment: This doesn't works T.T @flexaddicted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I achieved solve the problem: in the "Build phases" (in the properties of the project), I delete a copy of the bundle of the DB and back to added.

The problem was that this bundle was generated in the Derived Data folder, and although I will create new copies, this file is keeping deprecated. When I deleted all files and folders of Derived Data, xCode shows me several errors about this folder and related to the bundle. So, I build the datamodel again, copy the new bundle in the project, and add again (after delete the old bundle) in the "Build phases" of the project.

Comment: You had to completely rebuild your xcdatamodeld file? That's going to take me ages...

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I did this, but I think that when I said "build the datamodel again", I refer to compile it and generate again the respective classes

Comment: Ah that's not so bad then... I've sorted my issue now but next time I'll give that a go. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot simply upgrade the Database schema in Core Data without migrating it. This provides a "mapping" for the app to follow. Read through this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH6-SW1) for more info, and instructions on how to migrate.

Comment: The OP has removed the app from the simulator. So, this could be not the problem. See also his last comment.